# Kinneret water levels

Tags: historical, hydrology

I am looking for daily data for the water level of Kinneret over the years (ideally 20+ years).

Is there such thing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to scrape this, or whether it exists in an easier format:
https://www.gov.il/he/Departments/DynamicCollectors/kinneret_level?skip=0

Ah here you go: https://data.gov.il/dataset/https-www-data-gov-il-dataset-682/resource/2de7b543-e13d-4e7e-b4c8-56071bc4d3c8